# How to use Python imp.load_source() to deal with bytes paths on Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.5

imp.load_source() is defined in [imp](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/imp.py#l168) module in Python library. We have paths as bytes on UNIX system, so I am passing bytes pathname to the load_source function. However doing this results in the following traceback.

```
>>> imp.load_source(b'evolve', paths[6])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 168, in load_source
spec = util.spec_from_file_location(name, pathname, loader=loader)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 558, in spec_from_file_location
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 648, in is_package
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 59, in _path_split
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I have cross checked and my paths[6] is a bytes variable. After digging deep into the Python code, I found that at a [certain place](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#l63), the code calls rpartition() with a string variable passed into it.

It's quite obvious that Python will return an error because of that. How I can do what I wanted to so. Do passing the paths as unicode will work or there is any other library on Python 3.5 which can help in doing the same thing. I am aware about importlib module, can I use it instead of imp. Or there is another way around using the imp.load_source() only.

Answer (score 0):

Passing both `name` and `pathname` as unicodes worked for me. I used os.fsdecode() which is there in Python 3.5 to decode to unicodes. Since os.fsdecode() didn't exist in Python 2 and I wanted Python 2 compatibility as well, I made a new function which uses os.fsdecode() and called that.

```
import os
import sys
import imp

def osfsdecode(name):
    if sys.version_info[0] > 3:
        return os.fsdecode(name)
    return name

imp.load_source('evolve', os.fsdecode(paths[6]))
```

I also tried finding other libraries but was unable to find a good match. Though this does not certify they don't exist.